# Pipeline design pattern implementation using Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

Can someone guide me as how to implement the Pipeline design pattern using Spring Boot?

I understand that each Pipe step has to be implemented as a `@Service`. I would like to know if `@Ordered` can be added to have the steps executed without explicitly wiring the individual `@Service` classes as the number of pipes in my case could exceed 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like that:

```java
    public interface Pipe{
            void chain(Message input, Pipeline pipeline);
        }



    public class abstract AbstractPipe implements Pipe {

       public void chain(Message input, Pipeline pipeline){
          try {
            //Business process of pipe1 (i.e. process the message and return response (Result of processing))
            Response response = processMessage(input);
            //Sucessful while processing
            Message output = onSuccess(response, input);
            pipeline.next(output);
          }catch(Exception exception){
            //Failure while processing
            onError(exception, input);
           //Maybe, we can continue 
           //with an alternative message
          }
       }       

       public abstract Message onSuccess(Response response, Message originalMessage);
       public abstract void onError(Throwable error, Message input);

       public abstract Response processMessage(Message input);
     }

    @Service
    public class Pipe1 extends AbstractPipe {
    // Implementation of abstract methods
    }

    @Service
    public class Pipe2 extends AbstractPipe {
        // Implementation of abstract methods
    }

    @Service
    public class Pipe3 extends AbstractPipe {
        // Implementation of abstract methods
    }


    public interface Message {
        public Object get(String key);
    }
    public class MessageImpl implements Message {
        private final Map<String, Object> index;
        public MessageImpl(){...}
        public void set(String key, Objetc value){...}
        public Object get(String key){...}
    }
```

The `Pipeline` is a chain of Pipes. Each pipe executes a command and tell the pipeline to continue with a new message.

I'm not sure that Spring has an annotation called @Ordered. Maybe you mean [@Order](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html) which :

> defines the sort order for an annotated component.

I'm not sure that it can add something to the **Pipeline** implementation.

Hope that helps.